# Sequence of right differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sequence-of-function

Suppose $\left\lbrace f_n\right\rbrace _{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of continuous functions, each of which is right differentiable on $\left[ a, b\right) $. Suppose further that for some  $x_0 \in \left[ a, b\right) $    converges and that $f_i'(x+)$ converges uniformly to $g$ on $\left[ a, b\right) $. Then:

- $ f_n$ converges uniformly on $\left[ a, b\right) $ to a function f ; and
- $f$ is right differentiable on $\left[ a, b\right) $ and $f'(x+)=g(x)$ for all $x \in \left[ a, b\right)$.

Note: $f'(x+)$ is the right derivative of $f$

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false.  Consider the interval $ [a,b) = [0,2) $, and define the functions
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } 0 \leq x < 1 \\
n & \mbox{if } 1 \leq x < 2 \end{cases}
$$
These are right-differentiable with derivative $ f_n'(x+) \equiv 0 $, and converge on $ [0,1) $.  The sequence is a clear counter-example to your problem as stated.  Please be more careful to state *all* hypotheses of your problem, or indicate if you are not sure whether the statement is true or false.

Comment: Sorry, it's a sequence of continuous functions